# Package Explorer view in eclipse opens always in a new window

Tags: eclipse

When I open the package explorer perspective in eclipse, it always opens in a new window. I would want this to be attached to the editor. Please refer the image below

[image]

My preferences for perspective is as follows
[image]

I could not find a way to solve this. Please help. I am using eclipse Luna

Answer (score 1):

From navigation bar select 'Window' >>> 'New window'.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the editor area maximized, so there is no space for other views on the main window.

Double click on the editor tab bar to restore the editor area to normal (not maximized) and the package explorer should display as normal.

Comment: Thanks for pitching in. This did not help. I maximized myself for taking screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

Closing all open perspectives and opening package explorer again solved it.